# gitlab-runner gets occasionally 403 "Access Forbidden" while querying for jobs

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I have two Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS servers. One is running a gitlab-ee instance and the other one is running the gitlab-runners.

When I push code to the server, I noticed that it takes a long time for my shared runners to pick up the code and build it.

I looked into the gitlab-ee logs under `/var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/api_json.log` and saw that they very frequently get 403 errors.

```
{"time":"2018-09-03T17:58:29.432Z","severity":"INFO","duration":5.41,"db":1.34,"view":4.07,"status":403,"method":"POST","path":"/api/v4/jobs/request","params":{"info":{"name":"gitlab-runner","version":"11.2.0","revision":"35e8515d","platform":"linux","architecture":"amd64","executor":"docker","shell":"bash","features":{"variables":"[FILTERED]","image":null,"services":null,"artifacts":null,"cache":null,"shared":null,"upload_multiple_artifacts":null}},"token":"[FILTERED]","last_update":"c565c8f1c839e48b27a1758c04af7863"},"host":"gitlab.XXXX.XXX","ip":"XX.XX.XX.XX","ua":"gitlab-runner 11.2.0 (11-2-stable; go1.8.7; linux/amd64)","queue_duration":8.48}
{"time":"2018-09-03T17:58:29.621Z","severity":"INFO","duration":5.51,"db":1.26,"view":4.25,"status":403,"method":"POST","path":"/api/v4/jobs/request","params":{"info":{"name":"gitlab-runner","version":"11.2.0","revision":"35e8515d","platform":"linux","architecture":"amd64","executor":"docker","shell":"bash","features":{"variables":"[FILTERED]","image":null,"services":null,"artifacts":null,"cache":null,"shared":null,"upload_multiple_artifacts":null}},"token":"[FILTERED]","last_update":"6c328f52ff65c51b4b34b9c1ea26249e"},"host":"gitlab.XXXX.XXX","ip":"XX.XX.XX.XX","ua":"gitlab-runner 11.2.0 (11-2-stable; go1.8.7; linux/amd64)","queue_duration":9.43}
{"time":"2018-09-03T17:58:29.807Z","severity":"INFO","duration":5.5,"db":1.61,"view":3.8899999999999997,"status":403,"method":"POST","path":"/api/v4/jobs/request","params":{"info":{"name":"gitlab-runner","version":"11.2.0","revision":"35e8515d","platform":"linux","architecture":"amd64","executor":"docker","shell":"bash","features":{"variables":"[FILTERED]","image":null,"services":null,"artifacts":null,"cache":null,"shared":null,"upload_multiple_artifacts":null}},"token":"[FILTERED]","last_update":"7d3fda493909db2329c6a578ad9960ec"},"host":"gitlab.XXXX.XXX","ip":"XX.XX.XX.XX","ua":"gitlab-runner 11.2.0 (11-2-stable; go1.8.7; linux/amd64)","queue_duration":7.72}
```

Until, every so often, one manages to come through,

```
{"time":"2018-09-03T19:22:07.249Z","severity":"INFO","duration":24.36,"db":7.55,"view":16.81,"status":204,"method":"POST","path":"/api/v4/jobs/request","params":{"info":{"name":"gitlab-runner","version":"11.2.0","revision":"35e8515d","platform":"linux","architecture":"amd64","executor":"docker","shell":"bash","features":{"variables":"[FILTERED]","image":null,"services":null,"artifacts":null,"cache":null,"shared":null,"upload_multiple_artifacts":null}},"token":"[FILTERED]","last_update":"e0d8576707ef9261fd3e59106f8a2ba8"},"host":"gitlab.XXXX.XXX","ip":"XX.XX.XX.XX","ua":"gitlab-runner 11.2.0 (11-2-stable; go1.8.7; linux/amd64)","queue_duration":18.47}
```

This causes queue times of over 10 mintues.

I have tried to find the cause of this, but was unable to. The steps I have taken are:

- Deleted all the runners and recreated them.
- Verifying the runners, which works without any problems

It seems like [GitLab issuing temporary IP bans - 403 forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36298959/gitlab-issuing-temporary-ip-bans-403-forbidden) is very similar, but I do not have anything additionally installed. It is a vanilla gitlab-ee instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your GitLab instance behind a load balancer, by any chance? I've encountered a very similar situation with my self-hosted GitLab EE instance, in the past. GitLab was seeing all requests come in from the same IP address because of the load balancer, and would erroneously issue temporary bans all the time. I've encountered the 403 response on GitLab Runner job requests, among other things.

To fix my installation, I ended up turning off the rack attack filtering altogether. Though, there is a way to forward the actual client IPs, too.

Comment: It is not behind a load balancer, but all the runners were running on the same machine. This indeed seems to haven been the problem! I am now running only one runner which then autoscales to many and this works perfectly.